# Servlet Filter for security

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, filter

I am using Servlet filter for secure app,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HelloFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sarp.filter.HelloFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>login_form</param-name>
        <param-value>/loginForm.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HelloFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but if my servlets use jsp files I can not catch them

```
private void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/deniz.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

for example deniz.jsp appears without aouthentication , 
is there any solution?
thanks

Comment: The servlet filter is not a secure filter.

Comment: Using `forward` on any resource will forward the request **internally** without invoking the filter. Either extend the matching pattern to catch the urls of your servlets or implement the _security_ code in the servlet as well (not a good idea, by the way).

Comment: what do you offer for security ?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `FORWARD` behavior using the dispatcher tag in the `filter-mapping`

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HelloFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This information can be found in section `6.2.5` of the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

> New since version 2.4 of the Java Servlet specification is the ability
>   to configure filters to be invoked under request dispatcher forward()
>   and include() calls.
>
> By using the new  element in the deployment descriptor,
>   the developer can indicate for a filter-mapping whether he would like
>   the filter to be applied to requests when:
>
> 1. The request is being processed under a request dispatcher representing the Web component matching the  or
>       using a forward() call.
>
> This is indicated by a  element with value FORWARD

Comment: You need to use <dispatcher>REQUE£ST</dispatcher> else only forwarded requests will be caught be the filter. I suspect INCLUDE will be required as well. ERROR and ASYNC probably not but as it is a security filter...